Sum of limit and offset exceeded max value of 10000
I have a python script that is using aruba networks APIs to extract a list of all of the events in a given time slot (12h at a time). with the API (Events API Link), I am not able to get all of the events in the given time slot, and I am only able to get 1000 events at a time.
So, my thought process was to add an offset value of 1000 to the API call. so, every time the API is called, I will get 1000 events in my response, until I eventually start getting less than 1000 events. In which case, I will stop calling the API. However, When trying that out, I kept getting the error:
{'description': 'Sum of limit and offset exceeded max value 10000', 'error_code': '0002', 'service_name': 'Monitoring'} 
This error is happening because my offset is increasing by 1000 each time until it eventually reaches 10000 which is the limit. However, even though the offset limit is reached, there are still some events left inside aruba that have not yet been pulled.
So the two parts in my script are:
def get_events(access_token, offset, start_time, end_time):
        
    url = f"{baseurl}/monitoring/v2/events?limit=1000&offset={offset}&from_timestamp={start_time}&to_timestamp={end_time}"
    payload = {}
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token,
    }
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    json_data = response.json()
    print("DATA")
    print(json_data)

    return json_data


# Get the current date and time
current_datetime = datetime.now()
 
# Subtract one day
previous_day_datetime = current_datetime - timedelta(days=1)
date_str = previous_day_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
start_time = datetime_to_epoch(date_str, "12:00:00")
end_time = datetime_to_epoch(date_str, "23:59:59")


offset = 0

while True:
    response = get_events(get_access_token(), offset, start_time, end_time)
    count = response['count']
    if count < 1000:
        break
    offset += 1000

In the above code, if you notice inside the while loop statement. I constantly check if the number of events returned by the API call is less than 1000, in which case I know there are no more events to get.
what are some possible solutions to get more than 10000 entries? I'm still relatively knew to aruba and aruba APIs, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

You can paginate instead by breaking the time slot into smaller intervals. If you're looking at a 12-hour period, split it into smaller chunks, such as 1-hour intervals, and then aggregate the results.
